# Bad math environment delimiters

Tags: math-mode

I'm not after perfect  LaTeX  just working LaTeX.
I guess enclosed is a working example (part of a larger book).

There are lots of  bad math environment errors . But the pairs [ ...]  seem correct. Who sees te problem ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 


\begin{document}


(8) Ist $\theta \in \Theta \;,\;\Theta \subseteq \Re^{n}\;,\;n\ge 2$ , so 
m\"{u}ssen \textbf{Konfidenzbereiche} betrachtet werden , die nicht mehr

die einfache Gestalt von Intervallen oder Rechtecken haben . Vielmehr 
ergeben sich dann oft 

Ellipsen, Ellipsoide oder bananenartige Gebilde .

\underline {\textbf{Beispiele :}}

(1) $X_{1} ,X_{2} ,...,X_{n} \quad u.i.v.\;,\;X_{j} \quad \sim \quad N\left( {\mu 
,\sigma^{2}} \right)\;,\;\sigma^{2}$ bekannt ; sei $\mu \in \Theta 
\;:\;=\Re $ der unbekannte 

Parameter ; $\mbox{\bar{{X}}}=\mbox{(X}_{\mbox{1}} +\mbox{X}_{\mbox{2}} 
+\mbox{...}+\mbox{X}_{\mbox{n}} \mbox{)/n}$ .

Es ergibt sich ein zweiseitiges Konfidenzintervall (KI/CI) f\"{u}r den 
Parameter $\mu $ :
\[
\left( {\bar{{X}}-\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt n }\Phi^{-1}\left( {1-\frac{\alpha 
}{2}} \right),\bar{{X}}+\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt n }\Phi^{-1}\left( 
{1-\frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)} \right)
\]
Die einseitigen KI :
\[
\left( {-\infty \quad ,\quad \bar{{X}}+\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt n }\Phi 
^{-1}\left( {1-\alpha } \right)} \right)
\]
bzw.
\[
\left( {\bar{{X}}-\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt n }\Phi^{-1}\left( {1-\alpha } 
\right)\quad ,\quad +\infty } \right)
\]
(2) $X_{1} ,X_{2} ,...,X_{n} \quad u.i.v.\;,\;X_{j} \quad \sim \quad N\left( {\mu 
,\sigma^{2}} \right)\;,\;\sigma^{2}$ \underline {unbekannt} ; sei $\mu \in 
\Theta \;:\;=\Re $der unbekannte 

Parameter und $s^{2}$ der Standardsch\"{a}tzer f\"{u}r $\sigma^{2}$ ; 
$\mbox{\bar{{X}}}=\mbox{(X}_{\mbox{1}} +\mbox{X}_{\mbox{2}} 
+\mbox{...}+\mbox{X}_{\mbox{n}} \mbox{)/n}$ . 


\end{document}
```

Doc_H

Comment: what is the intention of the `\mbox` ? (they are just causing errors) `\mbox{(X}_{\ `  inside `\mbox` you are in text mode so math constructs like `_` and `\bar` do not work.

Comment: David :  As I'm not so advanced I did use a converter Word to LaTeX - that produced the mboxes.Maybe you could look from <Es ergibt sich ein ....> onwards. That would help. My idea was if I get  ~ 90%  Ok  I will achieve the rest manually.  Doc_H

Comment: When commenting out the mbox parts the rest is OK. So the largest number of errors are follow-up errors  from these mbox parts. I will clean them up and come back.

Answer (score 1):

`\mbox` always switches to text mode for printing the argument. But you need the math mode, so you have at least to remove the `\mbox` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 


\begin{document}


(8) Ist $\theta \in \Theta \;,\;\Theta \subseteq \Re^{n}\;,\;n\ge 2$ , so 
m\"{u}ssen \textbf{Konfidenzbereiche} betrachtet werden , die nicht mehr

die einfache Gestalt von Intervallen oder Rechtecken haben . Vielmehr 
ergeben sich dann oft 

Ellipsen, Ellipsoide oder bananenartige Gebilde .

\underline {\textbf{Beispiele :}}

(1) $X_{1} ,X_{2} ,...,X_{n} \quad u.i.v.\;,\;X_{j} \quad \sim \quad N\left( {\mu 
,\sigma^{2}} \right)\;,\;\sigma^{2}$ bekannt ; sei $\mu \in \Theta 
\;:\;=\Re $ der unbekannte 

Parameter ; $\bar{X}={(X_1 +X_2
+...+X_n )/n}$ .

Es ergibt sich ein zweiseitiges Konfidenzintervall (KI/CI) f\"{u}r den 
Parameter $\mu $ :
\[
\left( {\bar{{X}}-\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt n }\Phi^{-1}\left( {1-\frac{\alpha 
}{2}} \right),\bar{{X}}+\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt n }\Phi^{-1}\left( 
{1-\frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)} \right)
\]
Die einseitigen KI :
\[
\left( {-\infty \quad ,\quad \bar{{X}}+\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt n }\Phi 
^{-1}\left( {1-\alpha } \right)} \right)
\]
bzw.
\[
\left( {\bar{{X}}-\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt n }\Phi^{-1}\left( {1-\alpha } 
\right)\quad ,\quad +\infty } \right)
\]
(2) $X_{1} ,X_{2} ,...,X_{n} \quad u.i.v.\;,\;X_{j} \quad \sim \quad N\left( {\mu 
,\sigma^{2}} \right)\;,\;\sigma^{2}$ \underline {unbekannt} ; sei $\mu \in 
\Theta \;:\;=\Re $der unbekannte 

Parameter und $s^{2}$ der Standardsch\"{a}tzer f\"{u}r $\sigma^{2}$ ; 
$\bar{{X}}=(X_{1} +X_{2} 
+...+X_{n} )/n$ . 


\end{document}
```

Don't use that converter again, you needed to remove all the `\mbox` commands with their brackets to fix it.